# In emulator App working perfectly when I build APK that APK is not working in mobile

Tags: android

in my application,there are some reports which are fetching from different url.

In emulator fetching data from a url and displaying fine for all reports,
but after installing apk in mobile device all reports are fine except one report is coming error loading null, even url is fine and in url i am getting data, during emulator it was fine too.
but build apk and install in mobile its showing only error loading null.
please can anyone help me why its happening?

Comment: post logcat error

Comment: Connect your phone and launch the app to the connected device in debug mode and read the error logs. If you have further problems post the error logs here. **Always include error logs when posting questions about running into errors**

Comment: com.android.volley.servererror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

api/MobileAPI/GetSalesVsBudget?TenantId=-4817451041011483&AppUserId=0&FromDate=01 Apr 16&ToDate=02 May 17&LoggedIn=true

Problem in mobile it will not taking the data format so that i removed the space between the month and year it working.For mabile use this type of URL.

But in emulator working above URL dont no.

Answer (score 1):

disabled your instant run in your android studio

File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Instant Run->Uncheck First Checkbox

then after the run your a project and build APK

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Instant Run. Go to Settings and uncheck Enable Instant Run option and then try to build the apk.